# How to tell if rails is in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, production-environment

I used `script/server -e production` to start rails in production mode. It did and I got no errors. However how do I tell if it is in production mode? I tried a non-existent route, and I got a similar error page I did in development.

I thought if under production model, I get the 404 error page that is in my /public folder.

Does it mean it didn't start in production mode?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

2 easy ways:

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

if there are entries populating that log after you hit the app, you're in production mode.

second way:

in one of your views (probably the layout is good), just add

```
<%= "Environment: #{RAILS_ENV}" %>
```

And that will show you what the environment that you're running in.

**edit**

You will see the default exception page instead of the actual error pages on any environment   if the request is considered "local" (that is from localhost or 127.0.0.1), you can override this by adding this to your `ApplicationController`

```
def local_request?
  false
end
```

You can find this method in the docs in the [api](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionController/Rescue.html#M005437)

Comment: I'm unable to get the second way to work, but there are entries in my production.log saying I created a Task at X time. So why am I not getting the right 404 error page? Do I have to specify somewhere to provide the right error page? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got an error in my view and had to use @Krishnaprasad's approach instead.

Comment: Please note `RAILS_ENV` is deprecated.
Use `Rails.env` instead.

Answer (score 254):

If its Rails 3.1+, `Rails.env.production?` will return `true` when in production.

```
Rails.env.production?  #=> true  
Rails.env.staging?     #=> false
Rails.env.development? #=> false
```

Comment: `>> Rails.env` via `rails c` appears to display for any mode.

Comment: Everything with a questionmark is available. `Rails.env` is a String decorated with `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer.html

Comment: Just as a note, this also works in the rails console. On a production server I was able to run: rails console, then the command above.

Answer (score 39):

For modern Rails versions (3+), `Rails.env` returns the environment as a `String`:

```
Rails.env #=> "production"
```

There are also helpful accessors* for each environment that will return a `Boolean`:

```
Rails.env.production?  #=> true  
Rails.env.staging?     #=> false
Rails.env.development? #=> false
```

(*) There's a *gotcha* here: these aren't real accessors. They're just strings of letters and if they happen to match the current environment name, they return true. They fail silently. That means that you can be in production, but if have a typo in this code, you won't get an error, you'll simply get `false`:

```
Rails.env.producton?  #=> false
```

For that reason, I set constants in an initializer and only refer to those in the rest of my code. This lets the Ruby interpreter help me catch my own errors:

```
PRODUCTION = Rails.env.production?
DEVELOPMENT = Rails.env.development?
TEST = Rails.env.test?
```

Answer (score 8):

On your command line type `rails console`, then `Rails.env`.

Answer (score 3):

I found it much easier to just restart the rails server and read the second line on the command line:

Running `rails s -e production` outputs:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in `production` on http://localhost:3000
```

Had Webrick in the example but some people didn't understand how changing servers would just substitute the name.  Updated for clarity.

Comment: No one sane is using `WEBrick` in production.

Comment: Hauleth is absolutely correct.  This is simply to test what environment you're in while developing.

Comment: If this answer is trolling it's mastery!  Congratulations!

Answer (score -2):

command line alternative

$echo $RAILS_ENV

Comment: This will not work if the server was started with an inline ENV var.  That said, if this was done then a script / alias / etc should live somewhere on-disk, which will include the RAILS_ENV var.  One can search the disk for it, such as with `ack`

Comment: this does not work.... what is in the variable and how it is getting the environment ???