# How do I access a Rails configuration value during runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 2.3.x.  I would like a small section of code to run if and only if the `config.cache_classes` is true.  By default, that's true for production and false for development.

How do I access the value of config.cache_classes from outside of my environment.rb, development.rb, and production.rb files?  It's easy to tell if we are in production or development, `Rails.env` will give us the answer.  But there's no guarantee the developer hasn't set `config.cache_classes = true` in development.

I certainly understand that you do not generally want to run separate code paths in development and production.  In this particular instance, we are simply not performing some work on startup; if we need to perform it later, we will do so, both in development and production.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

For Rails 2, you can do:

```
Rails.configuration.cache_classes
```

If you ever switch to Rails 3, it'll be different; you can access the same value with:

```
Rails.application.config.cache_classes
```

Comment: Heh.  Knew it would be something obvious like that.  I tried Rails.config, didn't think to try that.  Thanks.  I'll be accepting this answer once the time limit expires.

Comment: There is an exception with perform_caching, which can be set per controller too, so you should access it per controller

Comment: For me it was `MyApp::Application.config.foo` (Rails 4.1).

Comment: From what I can see, they are identical [at least](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e749424dfa38a0300a621b772eae96f9cc5d2555#diff-a79c10f572ebe2d487fd1ec69eabf45a2cd0e011c7dd74555da695a6f222ae98R50) since [Rails 3.0.20](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5f34bd61b0a49478ddf6a9a69654b8e56f0f20d3#diff-a79c10f572ebe2d487fd1ec69eabf45a2cd0e011c7dd74555da695a6f222ae98R46).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you are in a module, you may need to access the root namespace.  This should provide access from anywhere in a universal way for rails 3+:

`::Rails.application.config`