# Sending email only in prodcution but not in development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an app that sends email and I configured mandrill in my application.rb file.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'translatr.herokuapp.com',
  user_name:            ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"], 
  password:             ENV["MANDRILL_PASSWORD"], 
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

However I don't want to send out mail during development and when testing but I do in production.Do I do this by moving this setting to production.rb?or is there another way to do it?

Comment: yes move it to production.rb

Comment: Yes you do move this smtp_settings block into your `production.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have this setting in `production.rb` only. Because there are other useful settings for the other environments:

In `test.rb` you will find something like:

```
# Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
# The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

This allows you to write specs that check if a mail would have been send on production by checking if `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size` increased.

And the development environment usually should not sent an email. It just logs into `development.rb` what email would be send on production. Also very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Move your settings to production.rb, then email will be sent in production only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the setting in application.rb you can check for current rails environment. If env is production call the mail method.

```
      send_mail if Rails.env.production?
```

[How to tell if rails is in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967809/how-to-tell-if-rails-is-in-production#answer-7144161)

Comment: This is not idea, because it litters your codebase with environment checks.