# Rails passenger server not running in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I have deployed my app to a production server. However I *thing* its not running in production mode. I say this because its sending mail based on settings in config/environments/development.rb. Here is my apache config...

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName nso.server.com
   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /home/name/nso/current/public
   RailsEnv production
   <Directory /home/name/nso/current/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Additonally I am using capistrano to deploy. All the capistrano stuff seems to be working OK. I do have this line in delpoy.rb

```
set :rails_env, "production"
```

Do I need it? What command can I run over on my server to see if its actually running in production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [How to tell if rails is in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967809/how-to-tell-if-rails-is-in-production)

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

or plug this

```
<%= "Environment: #{RAILS_ENV}" %>
```

into a view