# Gravatar image not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

I'm working through the Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and I've added code to display a user's Gravatar image. But it doesn't display.

This is my users helper

```
module UsersHelper
  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

And this is my show.html.erb

```html
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

This is the code when i inspect the element

```
    <img alt="humber" class="gravatar" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/8e92292186fbb306e253b08d0f3eb993">
    humber
```

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APHTo.png)

Comment: The code looks correct so you'll need to provide some additional info? What does the generated `<img>` tag look like? What happens when you visit the gravatar url you're using directly?

Comment: The email i'm using for the user is example@railstutorial.org which is on tutorial. and when i inspect the element on the browser i can see the image src.

Comment: Hmm, that looks good to me. Do you perhaps have some weird styling on the `.gravatar` CSS class that could be hiding it? Also, it could have something to do with the fact that you're trying to request a HTTPS resource from a non-HTTPS endpoint (e.g. http://localhost:3000) so try changing `gravatar_url` to be `"http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"`

Comment: Yes i had some weird stying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct, maybe the user that you are using has no email, or the email don't have an image in gravatar. I would suggest that you validate if the user have an email

```
def gravatar_for(user)
    if user.email?
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
        gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
        image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
    else
        image_tag("/img/avatar_default.png", alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
    end
end
```

Comment: I used your code still it doesn't show. is there any gem associated with this that am missing?

Comment: are you sure that you have a gravatar account? try with this email humber.m23@gmail.com in the user.

Comment: I added some details in the question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: seems like everything is ok, if you put the html generated in a html file, it works, then try removing the class in the image_tag. maybe is css issues then

Comment: Yes i had a problem with css, i set the img-display to none. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Probably you did one of exercises in tutorial and wrote custom class to hide images

```
img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: That was my problem, thanks for the pointer, I was banging my head for an hour trying to figure this one out.

Comment: This worked for me too - for people following Hartl's tutorial this is the most likely fix

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.... I tried adding an image tag and added the hash to it to see if it renders(please remove this and use gravatar_for once it works). It did, so here are the steps I did to improve the gravatar_for method. and I hope it helps.

1. Change the source of the gravatar to http:// from https://
2. Add more classes to gravatar in the gravatar_for method. It should read 
   image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar img img-responsive")

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it!

The tutorial directs you to download the image using curl; but this can results in a corrupt file. Why? When the book was written, the file on the website was a '.png' and today it is a '.svg'. The name has also changed from rails.png to rails-logo.svg.

By following the guide, you download a blank file and save it as a .png, and then rails gives you the middle finger.

Answer (score 0):

The email is fetching correctly? I have a method that does something similar, with a default url as param (in case the user email is not registered in gravatar. Check if it can help you:

```
  def avatar        
    default_url = "http://pcdoctorti.com.br/wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/images/default-user-image.png"
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(self.email).downcase
    "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"
  end
```

Ps: this is an instance method in User model

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried all the solutions given this far (well, the first three anyway) but was left scratching my head.  Then I removed the 'secure' from the URL and if worked just fine-- or at least for a link not associated with a gravatar. I mean, i was expecting the default gravatar image to show, and it did!

(I am also following Michael Hartl's course.)

```
<% hex_digest = Digest::MD5::hexdigest('my_name@gmail.com') %>
<% gravatar_url = "https://gravatar.com/avatar/#{hex_digest}" %>
<%= image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: 'gravatar image') %>
```

Comment: On reading the comments above, I found one that explained the need to remove the 'secure' bit in the URL. Bart Jedrocha explained that this change is needed when you're trying to access the gravatar from a non-secure (non-HTTPS) endpoint (like your local rails server, localhost:3000. However, when you deploy your app to a secure endpoint (say, Heroku) you might need to reinsert the 'secure' bit. You could do this dynamically by using Rails.evn.production? check. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967809/how-to-tell-if-rails-is-in-production).

Answer (score 0):

I am working through this course currently (Feb 2018) using the online version of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5) book.   I found the error to be a left over code in:

/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss

```
/* hide all images */
img {
  display: none;
}
```

Removing that allowed the gravatar image to display correctly for me

Answer (score 0):

[As of 2018](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#code-gravatar_for_helper)  Michael's helper function `gravatar_for` has the URL variable defined as:

`gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/gravatar/#{gravatar_id}"`

However [Gravatar's documentation](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) instructs you to use:

`gravatar_url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"`

The former did not work for me I was getting (404) and the image was appearing broken. The latter worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom.scss file comment out or remove the lines:

```
img {
    display: none;
}
```